# Trouble enabling webdav support with Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, webdav

I have a Windows Server Web 2008 SP2.  I am trying to connect to a webdav server (https) and copy some files from this server.

Mapping the network drive, or copying a file via Powershell, works fine from Windows 7 computers, but from the server it fails.  Is there something that I need to install/enable to get Windows Server Web 2008 to allow me to connect to a webdav folder?

Answer (score 1):

Install the Desktop Experience feature and make sure the Webclient service is running. Take a look at this: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/386/using-the-webdav-redirector/